# c++ - Convert an array of float to an array of unsigned char and write to file

Tags: c, arrays, file, io

I'm writing a PPM file writer. The file format description can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format). I want to write the file in binary format, which is the `P6` type.

> The P6 binary format of the same image represents each color component of each pixel with one byte (thus three bytes per pixel) in the order red, green, then blue. The file is smaller, but the color information is difficult to read by humans.

My image buffer is originally an array of `Vec3f`, which is inside a `float[3]` so I can manage to convert the `Vec3f` array to `float` array.

What I failed to do is convert the `float` array to an `unsigned char` array so that I can write to a `.ppm` file.

Here's my code:

```
void writePPM(char *fn, Vec3f *buffer, int w, int h) {
        FILE *fp = fopen(fn, "wb");
        unsigned char *char_buffer = new unsigned char[w*h*3];
        for (int i = 0; i < w*h; i+=3) {
            char_buffer[i] = (unsigned char)buffer[i].x();
            char_buffer[i+1] = (unsigned char)buffer[i].y();
            char_buffer[i+2] = (unsigned char)buffer[i].z();
        }
        fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n\255\n", w, h);
        fwrite(char_buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), w*h*3, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

> buffer[i].x(), buffer[i].y(), buffer[i].z() range from [0,255]

The generated image is a completely black one, but width and height matches my image buffer, so I thought the `fwrite` part is wrong. How can I fix it?

I'm also confused how `float` be converted to `char`? `char` is 8-bit and `float` is bigger so there must be some data loss?

Comment: C doesn't have `operator new`. Are you sure you're programming in C?

Comment: What's your question? If you're accommodating a float value to char then there will be loss of information.

Comment: @DeiDei It's actually a c++ project but I'm not using c++ style I/O.

Comment: What is the range of `x`, `y` and `z` value? You may need an adaptation.

Comment: @purplepsycho `x`, `y`, and `z` range from [0,255]. I've edited the question.

Comment: Not directly related, but you should check if `fopen` is successful.

Comment: What is `Vec3f`? Don't describe your code but show it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that is described in the text of the question

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès yes I saw it, but it's unclear and I hate description of code. But your answer is probably correct.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The file is opened in `"wb"` mode. Line feeds will not be converted to DOS format.

Answer (score 1):

buffer index check.

```
for (int i = 0; i < w*h; i+=3) {
    char_buffer[i] = (unsigned char)buffer[i/3].x();
    char_buffer[i+1] = (unsigned char)buffer[i/3].y();
    char_buffer[i+2] = (unsigned char)buffer[i/3].z();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess but I would expect a pixel specified as three floats would have each float in the range [0, 1] with 0 being black and 1 being white. Whereas I would expect your char based pixel would expect each element to be in the range [0, 255] with 0 being black and 255 being white.

The cast `(char) someFloat` converts a `float` to an `char` by truncating the fractional part, so all your pixels will end up black - or very nearly black.

Try multiplying the float by 255 before the cast (and make sure the `char` is unsigned) i.e. `(unsigned char)(float * 255)`